# python game 2048 out of list index

Tags: python, list

I was working on the coursera [python project 2048](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_yCiAGeHByt_1.py) using codesculpter.
The code works fine when I try `4 x 4` or `5 x 5`, but it shows error when `4 x 5` or any other when `height != width`. I think I must have messed up somewhere in the `__init__` or other places but I couldn't figure out.

Could someone give me some suggestions?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import poc_2048_gui
import random

# Directions, DO NOT MODIFY
UP = 1
DOWN = 2
LEFT = 3
RIGHT = 4

# Offsets for computing tile indices in each direction.
# DO NOT MODIFY this dictionary.
OFFSETS = {UP: (1, 0),
           DOWN: (-1, 0),
           LEFT: (0, 1),
           RIGHT: (0, -1)}

def merge(line):
    """
    Helper function that merges a single row or column in 2048
    """

    # creat output list and remove 0
    after_merge=[]
    storage = []


    for num_1 in range(len(line)):
        after_merge.append(0)
        if line[num_1] != 0 :
            storage.append(line[num_1])


    # sum number        
    for num_2 in range(len(storage)):
        if num_2+2> len(storage):
            break
        elif storage[num_2]==storage[num_2+1]:
            storage[num_2]*=2
            storage.pop(num_2+1)

    # replace 0 in after merge          
    for num in range(len(storage)):
        after_merge[num]=storage[num]

    return after_merge


class TwentyFortyEight:
    """
    Class to run the game logic.
    """

    def __init__(self, grid_height, grid_width):
        self.grid_height = grid_height
        self.grid_width = grid_width
        self.cell=[]
        self.indices = {}
        self.indices[UP] = [[0,n] for n in range(grid_width)] 
        self.indices[LEFT] = [[n,0] for n in range(grid_height)] 
        self.indices[RIGHT] = [[n, grid_width - 1] for n in range(grid_height)]
        self.indices[DOWN] = [[grid_height - 1, n]for n in range(grid_width)]

        self.ranges = {}
        self.ranges[UP] = grid_height
        self.ranges[DOWN] = grid_height
        self.ranges[LEFT] = grid_width
        self.ranges[RIGHT] = grid_width

        #self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        """
        Reset the game so the grid is empty except for two
        initial tiles.
        """
        self.cell = [[0*(col+row) for row in range(self.grid_height)] for col in range (self.grid_width)]
        for count in range(2):
            self.new_tile()

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Return a string representation of the grid for debugging.
        """
        a_str = ""
        for row in range(self.grid_height):
            for col in range (self.grid_width):
                a_str += ( str(self.cell[row][col]) + " " )
            a_str += '\n'
        return a_str


    def get_grid_height(self):
        """
        Get the height of the board.
        """
        # replace with your code
        return self.grid_height

    def get_grid_width(self):
        """
        Get the width of the board.
        """
        # replace with your code
        return self.grid_width

    def move(self, direction):
        """
        Move all tiles in the given direction and add
        a new tile if any tiles moved.
        """
        a_list = []
        has_moved = False
        for index in self.indices[direction]:
            for step in range(self.ranges[direction]):
                a_list.append(self.cell[index[0] + OFFSETS[direction][0] * step]
                              [index[1] + OFFSETS[direction][1] * step])
            merged_list = merge(a_list)

            if merged_list != a_list:
                for step in range(self.ranges[direction]):
                    self.cell[index[0] + OFFSETS[direction][0] * step]   \
                    [index[1] + OFFSETS[direction][1] * step] = merged_list[step]
                has_moved = True
            a_list = []

        if has_moved:
            self.new_tile()

    def new_tile(self):
        """
        Create a new tile in a randomly selected empty
        square.  The tile should be 2 90% of the time and
        4 10% of the time.
        """
        # replace with your code
        row=0
        col=0
        available_positions = []
        for row in range(self.grid_height):
            for col in range(self.grid_width):
                if self.cell[row][col] == 0:
                        available_positions.append([row, col])
        if not available_positions:
            print "There are no available positions."

        random_pos=random.choice(available_positions)
        rand_val=random.randint(1,10)
        if rand_val>=9:
            new_tile=4
        else:
            new_tile=2

        self.set_tile(random_pos[0], random_pos[1], new_tile)



    def set_tile(self, row, col, value):
        """
        Set the tile at position row, col to have the given value.
        """
        # replace with your code
        self.cell[row][col] = value

    def get_tile(self, row, col):
        """
        Return the value of the tile at position row, col.
        """
        # replace with your code
        return self.cell[row][col]



poc_2048_gui.run_gui(TwentyFortyEight(4, 4))
```

Comment: What result do you expect, and what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I didn't debug all the way but here's what I found. `cell` should have dimension `grid_height * grid_width`. Correct?

However, right before this loop:

```
for row in range(self.grid_height):
    for col in range(self.grid_width):
        print(row," ",col);
        if self.cell[row][col] == 0:
                available_positions.append([row, col])
if not available_positions:
    print "There are no available positions."
```

I found that the size of cell is reverse. That is `grid_width * grid_height`. Put these two lines before the nested loops to see for yourself.

```
print("cell size",len(self.cell)," ",len(self.cell[0]))
print("grid size",self.grid_height," ",self.grid_width)
```

This will cause `IndexError` in line `if self.cell[row][col] == 0:` when the dimensions are different. That being said, you should step through and see exactly how you fill in both the grid and the cell. Make sure they correspond correctly.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Yes, I didn't understand well how to set up 2D array. Also, thanks for your suggestions regarding the index error.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick debug and I was able to get a IndexError when calling move(). Looking through, you seem to expect self.cell to be populated, but it only is ever populated through your reset() function. You may not see this if your UI module calls reset when initializing...

There is a second IndexError then when the row and col are not the same number. This (as mentioned in the other answer) is because your 2D array representation is col * row, not row * col

below is the printout of (4, 6), which has 4 COLUMN and 6 ROW. You likely just need to swap the two in your representation:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

A potential improvement to your syntax, but you can initiate your cells as such (test with your usage...)

```
self.cell = [[[0] * self.grid_width] for row in xrange(self.grid_height)]
```

Lastly, I believe you may get an IndexError in your new_tile because Python lists begin at the 0th element. You'll want to iter 0 through n-1:

```
    for row in range(self.grid_height-1):
        for col in range(self.grid_width-1):
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not quite understand how to set up a 2D array before. For the code 
"self.cell = [[[0] * self.grid_width] for row in xrange(self.grid_height)]"
Somehow I thought it doesn't matter to put width in front or height in front. But it actually make a bit difference. Now I can see why I had that error. Thanks again and I really appreciate it!